# How to config wso2 Enterprise Service Bus for conditional messages

Tags: web-services, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I have a server and i can call my web-service from this server.
So i call web-service, the web-service send me a answer and  i want according answer run application.
For example:

```
    answer=curl -i  -X GET "http://myserver.com/getStaus";
     switch (answer)
        {
            case 'ON':
                saveToQueue('http://myserver.com/getApp1','ON');
                do
                    {
                        retryQueueForSend('ON');            
                    }while !(lengthQueueForSend('ON')==0)
                    break;
            case 'OFF':
                saveToQueue('http://myserver.com/getApp2','OFF');
                do
                    {
                        retryQueueForSend('OFF');            
                    }while !(lengthQueueForSend('OFF')==0)
                    break;

            case 'TimeOut':
                saveToQueue('http://myserver.com/getApp3','TimeOut');
                do
                    {
                        retryQueueForSend('TimeOut');            
                    }while !(lengthQueueForSend('TimeOut')==0)
                    break;
        }
public void saveToQueue(String LinkOfWebservice,String nameOfQueue)
{
...
...
..
}
public void retryQueueForSend(String nameOfQueue)
{
...
...
..
}
public int retryQueueForSend(String nameOfQueue)
{
...
...
return len;
}
```

So i want implement this scenario on wso2 Enterprise Service Bus(ESB).
I think i have to use wso2 Message Broker(MB).
Thanks in advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "run application"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSO2 ESB for this implementation.

Use REST API [1] to call your service in "http://myserver.com/getStaus". In out sequence of REST API, you can switch mediator[2] to identify response (Check whether ON, OFF or timeout). According to that perform your task.

You do not need WSO2 MB for this implementation.

Note: I assume you mean run app1 as calling a backend or running another API

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Working+with+APIs
[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Switch+Mediator

Comment: Thanks. I want add queue because  my Apps may not running and after try run it. I think Message Broker(MB) needed.

Comment: I am not clear about your scenario. If you adding WSO2 MB into scenario, you can do it through API.